# How to replace for loop having service calls using Streams (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert the following for loop code (note that crowdClient is a service call to a 3rd party service) :

```
private List<User> getFullUserDetails(CrowdClient crowdClient, List<User> unModifiableUserList) {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (User u : unModifiableUserList) {
        userList.add(crowdClient.getUserWithAttributes(u.getName()));
    }
    return userList;
}
```

To a much simpler and elegant code using Java 8 feature like streams.
I expect something like below (which doesn't work by the way):

```
private List<User> getUserDetails(CrowdClient crowdClient,
        List<User> unModifiableUserList) {
    return unModifiableUserList.stream()
            .filter(unModifiableUserList -> crowdClient.getUserWithAttributes(unModifiableUserList.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: use `map` instead of `filter`

Answer (score 2):

That filter should be a map...

```
unModifiableUserList.stream()
       .map(u -> crowdClient.getUserWithAttributes(u.getName()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Sounds good thanks, but one problem crowdClient throws some exceptions and using try catch block will not resolve the compilation errors. Any tips on that? Tks.

Comment: @nanospeck will not resolve? how come? why would you not do a `try { ...} catch` I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `filter` which is meant to filter through the existing list. `map` on the other hand will help you transform the existing list into the format you want.

```
private List<User> getUserDetails(CrowdClient crowdClient, List<User> unModifiableUserList) {
        return unModifiableUserList.stream()
                .map(user -> crowdClient.getUserWithAttributes(user.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: this is not going to compile... `unModifiableUserList.stream()` and `map(unModifiableUserList ->)`